# filter out the records with same id having different values in a column

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, subquery, group-by

Can anyone help me to solution for below issue.

```
create table [order1] (order_id int, CartTransaction_Id int, Status_Id int);
insert into [order1] values
(357488,87214,1),
(357489,87214,8),
(357490,87214,1),
(357491,87214,1),
(343980,87216,1),
(357483,87216,1);

create table [Status1] (Type VARCHAR(100), Status_Id int);
insert into [Status1] values
('New','1'),
('Awaiting Approval','8'),
('New','1'),
('New','1'),
('New','1'),
('New','1');

    select
A.Order_Id, A.CartTransaction_Id, A.Status_Id, B.Type, B.Status_Id
FROM order1 A
JOIN dbo.Status1 B ON dbo.A.Status_Id = dbo.B.Status_Id
--AND B.Type = 'New' 
order by A.CartTransaction_Id
```

Below was the output I am  getting from above query.

[image]

Below was the expected result

[image]

I need to populate the data only if status type was 'New' for all order_id's in group of CartTransaction_Id

From the giving I need to filter out CartTransaction_Id (87214) as one of the order_id status_type was on Awaiting Approval

Comment: Why wasn't order 357491 included? Or 357490?

Comment: if you check order_id 357491 or 357490 both are for under 87214 (cart transaction id). 
As mentioned I need to populate the data only if status type was 'New' for all order_id's in group of CartTransaction_Id

Comment: Why do you have the same status pair ('New', 1) repeated five times in the Status1 table? Also, are there any keys or indexes on the tables?

Comment: The answer for SQL Server and MySQL _may_ be different.  Pick one!  I'm removing the MySQL tag since the syntax does not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example do this:

```
select
A.Order_Id, A.CartTransaction_Id, A.Status_Id, B.Type, B.Status_Id
FROM order1 A
JOIN dbo.Status1 B ON dbo.A.Status_Id = dbo.B.Status_Id
where
not exists (select 1 from order1 o1 where o1.CartTransaction_Id = A.CartTransaction_Id and o1.Status_Id != 1)
order by A.CartTransaction_Id
```

If you have a lot of data, then you might to want to check other alternatives for this, like max + over

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  A.Order_Id, A.CartTransaction_Id, A.Status_Id, B.Type, B.Status_Id
FROM    order1 A
JOIN    Status1 B
    ON A.Status_Id = B.Status_Id
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 C.CartTransaction_Id FROM order1 C WHERE A.CartTransaction_Id = C.CartTransaction_Id AND C.Status_Id <> 1) C
WHERE   C.CartTransaction_Id IS NULL
ORDER BY A.CartTransaction_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your Status1 table need to have  multiple entries of "NEW"...
If not below query should work

```
select
A.Order_Id, A.CartTransaction_Id, A.Status_Id, B.Type, B.Status_Id
FROM order1 A
JOIN dbo.Status1 B ON A.Status_Id = B.Status_Id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order1 c WHERE c.CartTransaction_Id = 
a.CartTransaction_Id AND c.Status_Id <> 1)
order by A.CartTransaction_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need that many inserts to the [Status1] table

```
create table [Status1] (Type VARCHAR(100), Status_Id int);
insert into [Status1] values
('New','1'),
('Awaiting Approval','8');
```

Will be good enough for your joins.

Here's my take on the answer using ROW_NUMBER to get what you want.

```
;with Orders as (
    select A.Order_Id [OrderID]
    , A.CartTransaction_Id [CartTransactionID]
    , A.Status_Id [OrderStatus]
    , B.Type [StatusType]
    , B.Status_Id [StatusID]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.CartTransaction_Id, A.Status_Id ORDER BY A.CartTransaction_Id, A.Status_Id) RowNo
from order1 a join status1 b on a.status_id = b.status_id
)
select o.OrderID
    , o.CartTransactionID
    , o.OrderStatus
    , o.StatusType
    , o.StatusID 
from orders o
Where 1=1
and o.RowNo = 1
and o.StatusID = 1 --o.StatusType='new'
```